# Unable to build PlusClient with gradle (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-plus

I am using Android Studio. The following libraries can not be importing with gradle

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.GooglePlusUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient;
```

**build.gradle (Project):**

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.0'
    }
}
```

**build.gradle (Module: app):**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myApp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),       'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
}
```

**SDK:**

- Android Support Repository  Rev. 14
- Android Support Library     Rev. 22.1.1
- Google Play services        Rev. 23
- Google Repository           Rev. 16

**Gradle Build:**

```
Information:BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Information:0 errors
Information:0 warnings
```